# Android - JSONException No value for

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, jsonexception

I know that there are several questions posted on here with the same topic and error, but none of them indicate the same problem as mine, so I decided to post my question here, hoping that someone would help me point out the cause.
So I'm trying to implement the login feature in my app and here's the code:

```
if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(login_tag)){
                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            logoutUser(mContext);
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, json.toString(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json.getString(KEY_UID), json.getString(KEY_AVA), json_user.getString(KEY_BDAY), json_user.getString(KEY_COUNTRY), json_user.getString(KEY_PREF), json_user.getString(KEY_SPEND));  

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(mContext, DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            mContext.startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            ((Activity) mContext).finish();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

And this is the JSON response I got when logging in:

```
{
    "tag": "login",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "uid": "5123",
    "user": {
        "email": "abcxyz@gmail.com",
        "name": "abc",
        "avatar": "avatars/img_hzsxda_2013-03-18-11-03-33.jpg",
        "bday": "1991-02-01",
        "country": "Australia",
        "preferences": "none",
        "spending": "none"
    }
}
```

So apparently there is a value for `avatar`, but I still got this warning in my logcat:

```
03-18 12:06:36.972: W/System.err(24574): org.json.JSONException: No value for avatar
```

Since no value avatar is got, I can't complete `addUser`, hence login fails.
Please help me find the error and how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: how look your KEY_AVA?

Comment: This is how I declared it: `private static String KEY_AVA = "avatar";`

Comment: May I advise to not use your real e-mail in an example. You never know who else is looking on this website (hackers/sellers etc.)

Comment: Actually that's not my real email, but it could be someone else's so I changed it anyway. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are using the wrong object to get `avatar` value here `json.getString(KEY_AVA)`. It should be `json_user.getString(KEY_AVA)`.

Also, you can use `optString` instead of `getString` which just returns `null` if value doesn't exist, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the possibility to use opt instead of get! This saved me a lot of trouble!

Comment: Its not null but an empty string.

Comment: man.. why did it have to have these 2 different methods. its normal to have in some cases keys that have null as values.