# JSON Exception - No value for in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am getting this error message in my logcat `03-18 12:06:36.972: W/System.err(24574): org.json.JSONException: No value for title` an I am stuck here. I am using Gson to parse JSON data. Here is my MainActivity and Model class.

I looked into other questions posted for same JSON Exception but I couldn't find the solution so I posted this question for my project

Also please advise if I am using correct method to display the data in the `textview`.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String Logcat = "vmech";

Button searchButton;
EditText editTextSearch;
TextView textViewDisplayResult;
String newText;
String urlstring;

public static final String MyAPIKey =  "Your_Api_Key";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSerch);
    editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplayResult);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newText = editTextSearch.getText().toString();
            if(newText.length()>0){
                newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
                urlstring = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
                urlstring = urlstring + newText + "&maxResults=5" + "&key=" + MyAPIKey;

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a book name to search.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            new JSONTask().execute(urlstring);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "This is the Settings item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;

}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<BookInfoModel>>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<BookInfoModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlstring);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

            StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringbuffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = stringbuffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("items");

            List<BookInfoModel> bookInfoModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            String idText = null;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                BookInfoModel bookInfoModel = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(),BookInfoModel.class);

                bookInfoModelList.add(bookInfoModel);
            }


            return bookInfoModelList;

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null){
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<BookInfoModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        textViewDisplayResult.setText((CharSequence) result);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my model class for JSON data.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class BookInfoModel {
private List<Items> items;

private String totalItems;

private String kind;

public List<Items> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Items> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public String getTotalItems ()
{
    return totalItems;
}

public void setTotalItems (String totalItems)
{
    this.totalItems = totalItems;
}

public String getKind ()
{
    return kind;
}

public void setKind (String kind)
{
    this.kind = kind;
}


public class Items
{
    private SaleInfo saleInfo;

    private String id;

    private SearchInfo searchInfo;

    private String etag;

    private List<VolumeInfo> volumeInfo;

    private String selfLink;

    private AccessInfo accessInfo;

    private String kind;

    public SaleInfo getSaleInfo ()
    {
        return saleInfo;
    }

    public void setSaleInfo (SaleInfo saleInfo)
    {
        this.saleInfo = saleInfo;
    }

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public SearchInfo getSearchInfo ()
    {
        return searchInfo;
    }

    public void setSearchInfo (SearchInfo searchInfo)
    {
        this.searchInfo = searchInfo;
    }

    public String getEtag ()
    {
        return etag;
    }

    public void setEtag (String etag)
    {
        this.etag = etag;
    }

    public List<VolumeInfo> getVolumeInfo() {
        return volumeInfo;
    }

    public void setVolumeInfo(List<VolumeInfo> volumeInfo) {
        this.volumeInfo = volumeInfo;
    }

    public String getSelfLink ()
    {
        return selfLink;
    }

    public void setSelfLink (String selfLink)
    {
        this.selfLink = selfLink;
    }

    public AccessInfo getAccessInfo ()
    {
        return accessInfo;
    }

    public void setAccessInfo (AccessInfo accessInfo)
    {
        this.accessInfo = accessInfo;
    }

    public String getKind ()
    {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind (String kind)
    {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public class SearchInfo
    {
        private String textSnippet;

        public String getTextSnippet ()
        {
            return textSnippet;
        }

        public void setTextSnippet (String textSnippet)
        {
            this.textSnippet = textSnippet;
        }
    }

    public class AccessInfo
    {
        private String webReaderLink;

        private String textToSpeechPermission;

        private String publicDomain;

        private String viewability;

        private String accessViewStatus;

        private Pdf pdf;

        private Epub epub;

        private String embeddable;

        private String quoteSharingAllowed;

        private String country;

        public String getWebReaderLink ()
        {
            return webReaderLink;
        }

        public void setWebReaderLink (String webReaderLink)
        {
            this.webReaderLink = webReaderLink;
        }

        public String getTextToSpeechPermission ()
        {
            return textToSpeechPermission;
        }

        public void setTextToSpeechPermission (String textToSpeechPermission)
        {
            this.textToSpeechPermission = textToSpeechPermission;
        }

        public String getPublicDomain ()
        {
            return publicDomain;
        }

        public void setPublicDomain (String publicDomain)
        {
            this.publicDomain = publicDomain;
        }

        public String getViewability ()
        {
            return viewability;
        }

        public void setViewability (String viewability)
        {
            this.viewability = viewability;
        }

        public String getAccessViewStatus ()
        {
            return accessViewStatus;
        }

        public void setAccessViewStatus (String accessViewStatus)
        {
            this.accessViewStatus = accessViewStatus;
        }

        public Pdf getPdf ()
        {
            return pdf;
        }

        public void setPdf (Pdf pdf)
        {
            this.pdf = pdf;
        }

        public Epub getEpub ()
        {
            return epub;
        }

        public void setEpub (Epub epub)
        {
            this.epub = epub;
        }

        public String getEmbeddable ()
        {
            return embeddable;
        }

        public void setEmbeddable (String embeddable)
        {
            this.embeddable = embeddable;
        }

        public String getQuoteSharingAllowed ()
        {
            return quoteSharingAllowed;
        }

        public void setQuoteSharingAllowed (String quoteSharingAllowed)
        {
            this.quoteSharingAllowed = quoteSharingAllowed;
        }

        public String getCountry ()
        {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry (String country)
        {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public class Pdf
        {
            private String acsTokenLink;

            private String isAvailable;

            public String getAcsTokenLink ()
            {
                return acsTokenLink;
            }

            public void setAcsTokenLink (String acsTokenLink)
            {
                this.acsTokenLink = acsTokenLink;
            }

            public String getIsAvailable ()
            {
                return isAvailable;
            }

            public void setIsAvailable (String isAvailable)
            {
                this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
            }
        }

        public class Epub
        {
            private String acsTokenLink;

            private String isAvailable;

            public String getAcsTokenLink ()
            {
                return acsTokenLink;
            }

            public void setAcsTokenLink (String acsTokenLink)
            {
                this.acsTokenLink = acsTokenLink;
            }

            public String getIsAvailable ()
            {
                return isAvailable;
            }

            public void setIsAvailable (String isAvailable)
            {
                this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
            }
        }
    }

    public class SaleInfo
    {
        private RetailPrice retailPrice;

        private String saleability;

        private ListPrice listPrice;

        private Offers[] offers;

        private String buyLink;

        private String isEbook;

        private String country;

        public RetailPrice getRetailPrice ()
        {
            return retailPrice;
        }

        public void setRetailPrice (RetailPrice retailPrice)
        {
            this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
        }

        public String getSaleability ()
        {
            return saleability;
        }

        public void setSaleability (String saleability)
        {
            this.saleability = saleability;
        }

        public ListPrice getListPrice ()
        {
            return listPrice;
        }

        public void setListPrice (ListPrice listPrice)
        {
            this.listPrice = listPrice;
        }

        public Offers[] getOffers ()
        {
            return offers;
        }

        public void setOffers (Offers[] offers)
        {
            this.offers = offers;
        }

        public String getBuyLink ()
        {
            return buyLink;
        }

        public void setBuyLink (String buyLink)
        {
            this.buyLink = buyLink;
        }

        public String getIsEbook ()
        {
            return isEbook;
        }

        public void setIsEbook (String isEbook)
        {
            this.isEbook = isEbook;
        }

        public String getCountry ()
        {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry (String country)
        {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public class Offers
        {
            private RetailPrice retailPrice;

            private ListPrice listPrice;

            private String finskyOfferType;

            public RetailPrice getRetailPrice ()
            {
                return retailPrice;
            }

            public void setRetailPrice (RetailPrice retailPrice)
            {
                this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
            }

            public ListPrice getListPrice ()
            {
                return listPrice;
            }

            public void setListPrice (ListPrice listPrice)
            {
                this.listPrice = listPrice;
            }

            public String getFinskyOfferType ()
            {
                return finskyOfferType;
            }

            public void setFinskyOfferType (String finskyOfferType)
            {
                this.finskyOfferType = finskyOfferType;
            }
        }

        public class RetailPrice
        {
            private String amount;

            private String currencyCode;

            public String getAmount ()
            {
                return amount;
            }

            public void setAmount (String amount)
            {
                this.amount = amount;
            }

            public String getCurrencyCode ()
            {
                return currencyCode;
            }

            public void setCurrencyCode (String currencyCode)
            {
                this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
            }
        }

        public class ListPrice
        {
            private String amount;

            private String currencyCode;

            public String getAmount ()
            {
                return amount;
            }

            public void setAmount (String amount)
            {
                this.amount = amount;
            }

            public String getCurrencyCode ()
            {
                return currencyCode;
            }

            public void setCurrencyCode (String currencyCode)
            {
                this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
            }
        }
    }

    public class VolumeInfo
    {
        private String pageCount;

        private String averageRating;

        private ReadingModes readingModes;

        private String infoLink;

        private String printType;

        private String allowAnonLogging;

        private String publisher;

        private String[] authors;

        private String canonicalVolumeLink;

        @SerializedName("title")
        private String title;

        private String previewLink;

        private String description;

        private String ratingsCount;

        private ImageLinks imageLinks;

        private String contentVersion;

        private String[] categories;

        private String language;

        private String publishedDate;

        private IndustryIdentifiers[] industryIdentifiers;

        private String maturityRating;

        public String getPageCount ()
        {
            return pageCount;
        }

        public void setPageCount (String pageCount)
        {
            this.pageCount = pageCount;
        }

        public String getAverageRating ()
        {
            return averageRating;
        }

        public void setAverageRating (String averageRating)
        {
            this.averageRating = averageRating;
        }

        public ReadingModes getReadingModes ()
        {
            return readingModes;
        }

        public void setReadingModes (ReadingModes readingModes)
        {
            this.readingModes = readingModes;
        }

        public String getInfoLink ()
        {
            return infoLink;
        }

        public void setInfoLink (String infoLink)
        {
            this.infoLink = infoLink;
        }

        public String getPrintType ()
        {
            return printType;
        }

        public void setPrintType (String printType)
        {
            this.printType = printType;
        }

        public String getAllowAnonLogging ()
        {
            return allowAnonLogging;
        }

        public void setAllowAnonLogging (String allowAnonLogging)
        {
            this.allowAnonLogging = allowAnonLogging;
        }

        public String getPublisher ()
        {
            return publisher;
        }

        public void setPublisher (String publisher)
        {
            this.publisher = publisher;
        }

        public String[] getAuthors ()
        {
            return authors;
        }

        public void setAuthors (String[] authors)
        {
            this.authors = authors;
        }

        public String getCanonicalVolumeLink ()
        {
            return canonicalVolumeLink;
        }

        public void setCanonicalVolumeLink (String canonicalVolumeLink)
        {
            this.canonicalVolumeLink = canonicalVolumeLink;
        }

        public String getTitle ()
        {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle (String title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getPreviewLink ()
        {
            return previewLink;
        }

        public void setPreviewLink (String previewLink)
        {
            this.previewLink = previewLink;
        }

        public String getDescription ()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription (String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getRatingsCount ()
        {
            return ratingsCount;
        }

        public void setRatingsCount (String ratingsCount)
        {
            this.ratingsCount = ratingsCount;
        }

        public ImageLinks getImageLinks ()
        {
            return imageLinks;
        }

        public void setImageLinks (ImageLinks imageLinks)
        {
            this.imageLinks = imageLinks;
        }

        public String getContentVersion ()
        {
            return contentVersion;
        }

        public void setContentVersion (String contentVersion)
        {
            this.contentVersion = contentVersion;
        }

        public String[] getCategories ()
        {
            return categories;
        }

        public void setCategories (String[] categories)
        {
            this.categories = categories;
        }

        public String getLanguage ()
        {
            return language;
        }

        public void setLanguage (String language)
        {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getPublishedDate ()
        {
            return publishedDate;
        }

        public void setPublishedDate (String publishedDate)
        {
            this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
        }

        public IndustryIdentifiers[] getIndustryIdentifiers ()
        {
            return industryIdentifiers;
        }

        public void setIndustryIdentifiers (IndustryIdentifiers[] industryIdentifiers)
        {
            this.industryIdentifiers = industryIdentifiers;
        }

        public String getMaturityRating ()
        {
            return maturityRating;
        }

        public void setMaturityRating (String maturityRating)
        {
            this.maturityRating = maturityRating;
        }

        public class ImageLinks
        {
            private String thumbnail;

            private String smallThumbnail;

            public String getThumbnail ()
            {
                return thumbnail;
            }

            public void setThumbnail (String thumbnail)
            {
                this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
            }

            public String getSmallThumbnail ()
            {
                return smallThumbnail;
            }

            public void setSmallThumbnail (String smallThumbnail)
            {
                this.smallThumbnail = smallThumbnail;
            }
        }

        public class ReadingModes
        {
            private String text;

            private String image;

            public String getText ()
            {
                return text;
            }

            public void setText (String text)
            {
                this.text = text;
            }

            public String getImage ()
            {
                return image;
            }

            public void setImage (String image)
            {
                this.image = image;
            }
        }

        public class IndustryIdentifiers
        {
            private String type;

            private String identifier;

            public String getType ()
            {
                return type;
            }

            public void setType (String type)
            {
                this.type = type;
            }

            public String getIdentifier ()
            {
                return identifier;
            }

            public void setIdentifier (String identifier)
            {
                this.identifier = identifier;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the JSON data I m trying to Parse.

```
{

"kind": "books#volumes",
"totalItems": 1557,
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "books#volume",
        "id": "An4_e3Cr3zAC",
        "etag": "DWmqBRkB8dw",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/An4_e3Cr3zAC",
        "volumeInfo": {
            "title": "The Rules of the Game",
            "authors": [
                "Neil Strauss"
            ],
            "publisher": "Canongate Books",
            "publishedDate": "2011-09-29",
            "description": "If you want to play The Game you need to know The Rules This book is not a story.",
            "industryIdentifiers": [
                {
                    "type": "ISBN_13",
                    "identifier": "9781847673558"
                },
                {
                    "type": "ISBN_10",
                    "identifier": "1847673554"
                }
            ],
            "readingModes": {
                "text": true,
                "image": true
            },
            "pageCount": 352,
            "printType": "BOOK",
            "categories": [
                "Biography & Autobiography"
            ],
            "averageRating": 3.5,
            "ratingsCount": 82,
            "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
            "allowAnonLogging": true,
            "contentVersion": "1.7.6.0.preview.3",
            "imageLinks": {
                "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
                "thumbnail": "http://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
            },
            "language": "en",
            "previewLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=game&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
            "infoLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&dq=game&hl=&source=gbs_api",
            "canonicalVolumeLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Rules_of_the_Game.html?hl=&id=An4_e3Cr3zAC"
        },
        "saleInfo": {
            "country": "IN",
            "saleability": "FOR_SALE",
            "isEbook": true,
            "listPrice": {
                "amount": 399.0,
                "currencyCode": "INR"
            },
            "retailPrice": {
                "amount": 279.3,
                "currencyCode": "INR"
            },
            "buyLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&dq=game&hl=&buy=&source=gbs_api",
            "offers": [
                {
                    "finskyOfferType": 1,
                    "listPrice": {
                        "amountInMicros": 3.99E8,
                        "currencyCode": "INR"
                    },
                    "retailPrice": {
                        "amountInMicros": 2.793E8,
                        "currencyCode": "INR"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "accessInfo": {
            "country": "IN",
            "viewability": "PARTIAL",
            "embeddable": true,
            "publicDomain": false,
            "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
            "epub": {
                "isAvailable": true,
                "acsTokenLink": "http://books.goo"
            },
            "pdf": {
                "isAvailable": true,
                "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books/download/The_Rules_of_the_Game-sample-pdf.acsm?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
            },
            "webReaderLink": "http://books.google.co.in/books/reader?id=An4_e3Cr3zAC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api",
            "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
            "quoteSharingAllowed": false
        },
        "searchInfo": {
            "textSnippet": "He&#39;s tested the specific material."
        }
    }
 ]
```

}

Here is the stacktrace form logcat. https://codeshare.io/Ag78v

Comment: Post a sample of the JSON you're parsing.

Comment: 'No value for title" means there is no value for title in response ..Check your response.

Comment: 'No value for title'  taht means in your json res[ponse does not have "title" tag

Comment: @sunilsunny but when I debugged the code I am getting the entire Json data in the `finalObject ` of the `JSONObject` and at the end of the for loop it is giving error in logcat as `No vlaue for title`.

Comment: @muruga5000 My Json response does have a `title` tag.

Comment: @Vibhor may be you will be passing the wrong array in the GSON parsing. kindly check there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - JSONException No value for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477304/android-jsonexception-no-value-for)

Comment: @jankigadhiya its not a duplicate of the link u mentioned

Comment: how it is not duplicate @Vibhor it the same error.!!

Comment: Upload your stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

One of Your ListItem VolumeInfo have null value for title. By default Gson wont parse null value. But you can make to ignore null values when parsing. by doing the following.

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

Try this.

Comment: It was `VolumeInfo volumeinfo` previously and then I changed it to `List` but the problem still remains the same `No vlaue for title`.

Comment: your items list have multiple objects? or this one alone. @Vibhor

Comment: Yes it does have multiple objects. Not this items class but entire BookInfoModel Class.

Comment: Well it worked. Thanks. its not giving that `No value for title` but my app is crashing due to textview in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: it's just a string know. check the string.isEmpty? before adding it to textview. @Vibhor

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Items class with below:

```
public class Items
{
private SaleInfo saleInfo;

private String id;

private SearchInfo searchInfo;

private String etag;

private VolumeInfo volumeInfo;

private String selfLink;

private AccessInfo accessInfo;

private String kind;

public SaleInfo getSaleInfo ()
{
    return saleInfo;
}

public void setSaleInfo (SaleInfo saleInfo)
{
    this.saleInfo = saleInfo;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public SearchInfo getSearchInfo ()
{
    return searchInfo;
}

public void setSearchInfo (SearchInfo searchInfo)
{
    this.searchInfo = searchInfo;
}

public String getEtag ()
{
    return etag;
}

public void setEtag (String etag)
{
    this.etag = etag;
}

public VolumeInfo getVolumeInfo() {
    return volumeInfo;
}

public void setVolumeInfo(VolumeInfo volumeInfo) {
    this.volumeInfo = volumeInfo;
}

public String getSelfLink ()
{
    return selfLink;
}

public void setSelfLink (String selfLink)
{
    this.selfLink = selfLink;
}

public AccessInfo getAccessInfo ()
{
    return accessInfo;
}

public void setAccessInfo (AccessInfo accessInfo)
{
    this.accessInfo = accessInfo;
}

public String getKind ()
{
    return kind;
}

public void setKind (String kind)
{
    this.kind = kind;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the serializedName annotation. Use it as follows in your model.

```
     public class Items    
      {
        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private SaleInfo saleInfo;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private String id;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private SearchInfo searchInfo;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private String etag;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private VolumeInfo volumeInfo;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private String selfLink;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private AccessInfo accessInfo;

        @SerializedName("Your-key-from JSON Response")
        private String kind;

        public SaleInfo getSaleInfo ()
        {
            return saleInfo;
        }

        public void setSaleInfo (SaleInfo saleInfo)
        {
            this.saleInfo = saleInfo;
        }

        public String getId ()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId (String id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
   }
```